# Primefaces Can i preselect the first item of an orderList?

Tags: primefaces

I'm using `orderList` similar to the one shown in the `Showcase`. To make it clearer for the user what that they can navigate/order the list, I want to preselect the first item of my list. Unfortunately, I can't find any advice on how to do that or if it is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if by preselect the first item you mean highlight it, you can do it using JS/CSS, including the ui-state-highlight class in the first item.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

You have to use Jquery because orderList doesn't support selection.

1) Add a styleclass to your orderList, in my case: orderList

```
<p:orderList value="#{usuarioBean.roles}" 
converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" var="r"
itemLabel="#{r.descripcion}" itemValue="#{r}" styleClass="orderList">

     <p:column>
             #{r.descripcion}
     </p:column>
 </p:orderList>
```

2) Define a jquery function:

```
function selectFirst(){
        jQuery('.orderList tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) .ui-orderlist-list li:first-child').addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    }
```

3) Call selectFirst() at start page if your orderList is in page or when opening a dialog if orderList is in a dialog.

Tested on Primefaces 4.0, Java 7